# How can I get some records from a sql server table which contain the most up-to-date information?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sql server table:

```
|infrastructureName|sessionDate            |projectName|idThreat|
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|1
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|2
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|3
|infr1             |2019-06-25 07:49:26.133|projectMain|1
|infr2             |2019-06-25 10:13:30.293|projectMain|1
|infr3             |2019-06-25 12:49:35.383|projectMain|1
|infr3             |2019-06-25 15:49:38.383|projectMain|1
```

All the four fields are primary key.

I want to obtain the following table:

```
|infrastructureName|sessionDate            |projectName|idThreat|
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|1
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|2
|infr1             |2019-06-25 08:49:02.383|projectMain|3
|infr2             |2019-06-25 10:13:30.293|projectMain|1
|infr3             |2019-06-25 15:49:38.383|projectMain|1
```

So, I want to get the **most recent** records of all infrastructures that belong to a project.

How can I do that in SQL server?

OUTPUT: [OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ItW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a CROSS APPLY and get the max sessionDate for each infrastructureName and then filter where it equals that:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [infrastructureName] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [sessionDate] DATETIME
      , [projectName] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [idThreat] INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [infrastructureName]
                        , [sessionDate]
                        , [projectName]
                        , [idThreat]
                      )
VALUES ( 'infr1', '2019-06-25 08:49:02.383', 'projectMain', 1 )
     , ( 'infr1', '2019-06-25 08:49:02.383', 'projectMain', 2 )
     , ( 'infr1', '2019-06-25 08:49:02.383', 'projectMain', 3 )
     , ( 'infr1', '2019-06-25 07:49:26.133', 'projectMain', 1 )
     , ( 'infr2', '2019-06-25 10:13:30.293', 'projectMain', 1 )
     , ( 'infr3', '2019-06-25 12:49:35.383', 'projectMain', 1 )
     , ( 'infr3', '2019-06-25 15:49:38.383', 'projectMain', 1 );


SELECT      [a].*
FROM        @TestData [a]
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT MAX([aa].[sessionDate]) AS [MostRecentseesionDate]
                FROM   @TestData [aa]
                WHERE  [aa].[infrastructureName] = [a].[infrastructureName]
            ) AS [b]
WHERE       [b].[MostRecentseesionDate] = [a].[sessionDate]
ORDER BY    [a].[infrastructureName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT infrastructureName,sessionDate,projectName
FROM
(
SELECT infrastructureName,sessionDate,projectName, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY infrastructureName, projectName  ORDER BY sessionDate DESC) AS latest
FROM <YourTable>
)DT WHERE latest = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX()`

```
SELECT infrastructureName,
projectName, 
idThreat,
MAX(sessionDate) AS sessionDate

FROM your_table

GROUP BY infrastructureName,projectName,idThreat
```

Your output should not be like that. I'm confused. Here is a brute force way to try and get your desired output without knowing more about your data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(infrastructureName)) AS infrastructureName,
LTRIM(RTRIM(projectName)) AS projectName, 
MAX(sessionDate) AS sessionDate,
LTRIM(RTRIM(idThreat)) AS idThreat

FROM your_table

GROUP BY 
LTRIM(RTRIM(infrastructureName)),
LTRIM(RTRIM(projectName)), 
LTRIM(RTRIM(idThreat))
```

Comment: @inevthor Just add one more column. Answer updated.

Comment: This doesn't work because I get all the record of my table (so I have rows with the same infrastructureName but different sessionDate (from the oldest to the most recent - I want only the recent rows)

Comment: @inevthor I can assure you that my query here with your sample data provides your exact expected query. If it is different in your live environment, there is something else you are not providing.

Comment: No, my table is longer than this sample data but the columns are the same. Argh SQL!!

Comment: @inevthor Well here is how it works: the query is finding every unique combination of threatID, infraname, and projectName in your table, and then finding the highest available sessionDate for that unique combination. Add your output from your live environment to the post and I can look at what the issue is.

Comment: It seems like the `MAX()` function doesn't work in my case but I don't know why.

Comment: @inevthor Bummer. Without your output, I can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: see OUTPUT image

Comment: @inevthor Yeah thats bizarre. You are using the query I provided exactly? With max() and the group by line?

Comment: Yes, my query is: 
SELECT infrastructureName, projectName, 
MAX(sessionDate), idThreat from MYTABLE group by infrastructureName, projectName, idThreat

Comment: @inevthor Try my new query I added. If that doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas without knowing more about your table/data. Go ahead and add the table definition to the post as well.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work! I'm getting the same output of the first solution

Comment: So, I can do another thing: instead of querying my DB once, I can do n query (n is the number of infrastructures). I select rows which have projectName = X and infrastructureName = Y, with the most recent sessionDate. I know that one query is better than n, but I must do it!